# How can I customize the message bubble to include also the name of the user and time of the message in react native gifted chat?

Tags: react-native, chat, react-native-gifted-chat

I am using [gifted chat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gifted-chat) library in react native but the default view is to display only the avatar and the message in the bubble. I am building a group chat and I want to also display the name of the user in each bubble and the time the message was sent.

I added `renderMessage(props) {...}` property and if I return here a custom `View` with `Text` I can display the name of the user, but I am losing all the formatting that is already made by the library.

Is there a way to toggle to show the `user.name` of the message without rebuilding all the style from ground? I didn't found on the documentation something like this and I think it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use`renderUsernameOnMessage={true}` in the GiftedChat component